What is a union? How is a union created? What are union restrictions?
In states within the United States (pick Arizona for example), what is a labor union? I'm not looking for the "organization that represents employees" answer. I'm looking for the legal definition of what a union is. Is it a corporation? Can it be an LLC? Can it be a sole proprietor? Is it a business (corporation/LLC/sole proprietor) that has a tax status?
Other than rounding up employees to vote on union representation, how are unions created? Is it simply filing a corporation (in Arizona, Corporation Commission) articles of incorporation, getting an EIN from the IRS, getting a bank account, signing CBA contracts, and taking parties to court/arbitration? Can a union make money other than member dues? Can a union own/operate a school? Do unions have to behave a certain way?
That goes into the next question, what can and can't unions do? Are there ways around not being able to do something as a union by simply not technically falling under a statutory definition of a "union"?
For example, a charity doesn't necessarily need to be a 501-c-3 (tax designation) organization. It could just be a plain corporation that simply chooses to do charitable work, regardless of tax designation.
Can a union be the same? A corporation or a sole proprietor just simply act like a union without any special government designation?

We are not gong to teach you the National Labor Relations Act and subsequent National Labor Relations Board rulings on Stack, plus all related Federal and State employment law.
